# Add new options to the form as the users progress

Tags: html, forms, multiple-choice

I'm looking for how to make new options appear in the form as the users answer it.

For exmaple, let's say I have a drop list "gender" with the options "male", "female", and "robot". If the user choose "male" or "female", a check list would appear under the drop list with the option "married", "single".

If the user choose "robot" instead, it would appear a checklist under the drop list with the options "first generation" and "second generation".

How should I do this? Is there a specific name for this kind of form?

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the onchange event for your select, check the value inside the function and show the appropriate options.

If you're using a framework like Angular you can just use *ngIf.

Comment: Man i have been looking how to use "onchange" for forms but nothing i try is working, can you pass me a good tutorial?